# "Dann": Welche Stellung kann dieses Wort im Satz haben?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Immer wenn ich Deutsch sprechen möchte, stolpere ich über diesen Gedanken: *Kann das Wort* **dann** *mit dieser Satzstellung richtig sein?* Beispielsweise:

> Dann er fährt nach Berlin.
>
> [Dann](1) [SUBJEKT](2) [VERB](3) [PRÄPOSITION](4) [SUBSTANTIV](5)
>   [PUNKT](6)

Hier ist das Wort *dann* vor dem Subjekt *er* und ich frage mich, ob die Position (1) für *dann* richtig ist.

Ist das möglich?

Comment: Ich habe ein paar Änderungen vorgenommen. Ich hoffe, dabei deine Frage nicht verfälscht zu haben. - Zur Frage: Ich fürchte, dass die Antwort kein einfaches "ja" oder "nein" sein kann, denn: Ja, "dann" kann als erstes Wort verwendet werden. Aber die weitere Satzstellung stimmt nicht, denn Aussagesätze im Deutschen sind V2-Sätze. Das bedeutet, dass das Verb an zweiter Stelle stehen muss (womit das Subjekt an dritte Stelle rückt.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Dann* ist ein Temporaladverb. Im gegebenen Satz gibt es zwei Adverbien, nämlich Zeit und Ort. Es gibt im Deutschen die Tendenz, dass Zeit vor Ort kommt. Die 'natürliche' Reihenfolge (auf SPO basierend) ist hier

```
Subjekt Prädikat Adverbien
        Verb     Zeit   Ort
Er      fährt    dann   nach Berlin.
```

In diesem kurzen, einfachen Satz gibt es nicht viele Variationen. Das Verb muss in zweiter Position bleiben (die vielleicht wichtigste Regel) und die Zeitangabe kommt vor der Ortsangabe. Folglich bleibt nur eine Alternative:

```
Adverb Prädikat Subjekt Adverb
Zeit   Verb             Ort
Dann   fährt    er      nach Berlin.
```

Bedingt ist noch der folgende Satz akzeptabel, ist aber absolut unnatürlich. Im Englischen ist meiner Meinung nach die Reihenfolge Ort vor Zeit ("He travels to Berlin tomorrow."), im Deutschen rate ich dir davon aber ab.

> *Er fährt nach Berlin dann.

Zu beachten ist noch Folgendes:

> …, denn er fährt dann nach Berlin.
>   …, denn dann fährt er nach Berlin.
>   *…, denn er fährt nach Berlin dann.

Für diese Sätze gilt das Gleiche wie oben. Das *denn* ist eine nebengeordnete Konjunktion und nimmt die Position 0 im Satz ein. Das Verb kommt in Position 2 und das Zeitadverb vor Ort.

Zum Abschluss das Ganze noch in einem Nebensatz:

> …, weil er dann nach Berlin fährt.
>   *…, weil er nach Berlin dann fährt.
>   *…, weil er fährt dann nach Berlin.
>   *…, weil dann fährt er nach Berlin.
>   *…, weil er fährt nach Berlin dann.

Strikt genommen ist nur der erste Satz korrekt. Der zweite hat die unnatürliche Wortstellung Ort vor Zeit, ist daher nicht zu empfehlen. Die Sätze 3–5 sind in sofern falsch, weil das Verb in einem Nebensatz am Ende stehen muss. Es bürgert sich aber mehr und mehr ein, dass ein mit *weil* eingeleiteter Satz die Wortstellung eines Hauptsatzes adaptiert, deswegen habe ich der Vollständigkeit halber diese Varianten mit aufgezählt.
Als Referenz aber: Das einzig Richtige im Nebensatz ist:

```
Konjunktion Subjekt Adverbien          Prädikat
                    Zeit   Ort         Verb
…, weil   er      dann   nach Berlin fährt.
```

Auch hier gilt: Zeit vor Ort.

Edit:
(Mindestens) Eine Sache habe ich noch unterschlagen. Ein entscheidender Grund, um die Wortstellung zu ändern, ist die Betonung bestimmter Wortteile. Nehmen wir mal an, jemand stellt diese Frage:

> Wohin fährt er dann?

Der Schwerpunkt der darauffolgenden Antwort ist der Ort. Man möchte also "nach Berlin" im Folgenden hervorheben. Die Antwort würde also lauten:

> Nach Berlin fährt er dann.

Natürlich ist die zuvorgehende Frage nicht notwendig. Wann immer man den Ort hervorheben will, steht es einem frei, diesen nach vorne zu ziehen. In der gesprochenen Sprache wird "nach Berlin" dann zusätzlich durch entsprechende Intonation hervorgehoben.

Answer (score 6):

Der Satz kommt so nicht vor.

1. Eine mögliche Variante ist:

   > Dann fährt er nach Berlin.

   Dies wird verwendet, wenn der Fokus auf der zeitlichen Reihenfolge liegt, z. B.:

   > Erst fährt er nach Köln, dann fährt er nach Berlin.
2. Eine weitere Variante ist:

   > Er fährt dann nach Berlin.

   Dies wiederum wird verwendet, wenn der Fokus auf der Person liegt, z. B.:

   > Sie fährt nach Köln und er fährt dann nach Berlin.

In dem Satz hört sich das Wort *danach* besser an. Wenn beide gleichzeitig fahren, lässt man *dann* weg.

Wenn man andere Zeitformen nutzt, können die Wörter nochmal anders sortiert sein:

> Dann wird er nach Berlin fahren. (Futur I / Zukunft)
>    Dann ist er nach Berlin gefahren. (Perfekt / vollendete Vergangenheit)

Comment: Sind sie 100% sicher? Muss dieses Wort entweder in der ersten Stelle oder in der dritten Stelle stehen?

Comment: @MarinosAv: Nicht zwingend. Entscheidend ist die Position des Verbs an zweiter Stelle.

Comment: @Stephie dat bedeutet dass dieses Wort entweder erst oder dritte sein kann am Anfange des Satzes? richtig?

Comment: @Marinos Sv: Ich bin deutscher Muttersprachler, deshalb kann ich dir sagen, wie der Satz richtig ist, aber ich kann dir leider nicht sagen, welche Regeln dafür gelten. Mögliche Varianten sind: "Dann fährt er nach Berlin." (wenn der Fokus auf der zeitlichen Reihenfolge liegt, z.B. "Erst fährt er nach Köln, *dann fährt er nach Berlin*") oder "Er fährt dann nach Berlin" (wenn der Fokus auf der Person liegt,  z.B. "Sie fährt nach Köln und *er fährt dann nach Berlin*", in dem Satz hört sich das Wort "danach" besser an. Wenn beide gleichzeitig fahren, lässt man "dann" weg.)

Comment: "Danach" ist natürlich (i.d.R.) nur im ersten Satz sinnvoll. Im zweiten will man selten die zeitliche Reihenfolge mit einbringen; dort ist es eher "zu dem Zeitpunkt" oder je nach Kontext ist auch "in diesem Falle" möglich.